# Parallel.Invoke is executing first method only

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, linq

I've tried this

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => Method1(), () => Method2());
```

to start **Method1** & **Method2** actioning at a same time. But **Method1** only is getting executing. Any solution please.

In continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603506/how-to-cancel-the-thread-after-timeout), I've added below code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); cts.Cancel(); });
        ProcessFiles(cts.Token);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void ProcessFiles(CancellationToken cts)
    {
        try
        {
            LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(2);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);

            Parallel.Invoke(
                () => Method1(cts, tasks, factory),
                () => Method2(cts, tasks, factory));

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.Where(t => t != null).ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSuccessful completion.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (AggregateException aex)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void Method1(CancellationToken cts, List<Task> tasks, TaskFactory factory)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;
            var t = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method 1 --- {0} --- {1}", i1, GetGuid());
            }, cts);

            tasks.Add(t);
        }
    }

    private static void Method2(CancellationToken cts, List<Task> tasks, TaskFactory factory)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;
            var t = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method 2 --- {0} --- {1}", i1, GetGuid());
            }, cts);

            tasks.Add(t);
        }
    }

    private static Guid GetGuid()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

O/P: Only Method1 is invoking. Method2 is not.

[image]

Comment: Method 1 is queuing up a bunch of tasks before Method 2 gets a chance. Then, you time out before the Method 2 tasks even begin. Put some Console.WriteLines (or Thread.Sleep()) right before `factory.StartNew()` and it'll introduce a delay enough for you to see the Method 2's get mixed in.

Comment: Rob is correct - but there are some other issues.  Also, look into Task.Delay and note that comparing cts to null is incorrect (it's a struct - it's never null) - you probably mean something like cts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested

Comment: I can see both method execution after adding  Console.WriteLines (or Thread.Sleep()). Thanks

Comment: Please note, that runnig Method1() and Method2() at the same time introduces race condition on line "tasks.Add(t)", because class List<Task> is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see both methods are executing after adding Console.WriteLines (or Thread.Sleep()) right before factory.StartNew().

Thanks Rob for solution